# How to select Windows Server 2012 for Web Sites Preview on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How do I select Windows Server 2012 for a Web Sites Preview on Azure? Or is Server 2012 not available yet for Web Sites Preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get to select Windows Server 2012 (or for that matter any OS type) for a Windows Azure Website. You only choose them when you deploy your application as a Cloud Service (PaaS) or when creating a Windows Azure Virtual Machine (IaaS).

Comment: So currently the site is hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2. So will I be migrated up, or at some point in the future when I create a new Web Site it will select Windows Server 2012?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can select an operating system version with Windows Azure Web Sites.  If your application has OS specific needs, you should probably consider Cloud Services.